# Individual label position across facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, ggpubr

I am using the ggpubr package to add regression equations and R-Square to my plots. This works great so far.

However, I have multiple facets, and for some of the facets the position of the text label overlaps with the regression line. This is the code I am using:

```
library(ggpubr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- iris

ggscatter(df, x = "Sepal.Length", y = "Sepal.Width", facet.by = "Species", add = "reg.line") +
  stat_regline_equation() +
  stat_cor(aes(label = paste(..rr.label.., ..p.label.., sep = "~`,`~")),
           label.y = 4.2)
```

Is there a way to set the position of the text label individually for each facet?

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was to use `after_stat` to set the label positions based on the panel. However, as it turned out `label.x`, ... aren't aesthetics. Second thought was to pass vectors but that did not work either.

Hence, the only option I could come up with to place the text labels individually for each facet would be to use multiple `stat_regline_equation` and `stat_cor` layers. To this end I use a dataframe to specify the label positions. Afterwards split your data and the labels dataframe by the faceting variable and use e.g. `purrr::map2` to add your labels:

```r
library(ggpubr)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
library(ggplot2)

df <- iris

df_split <- split(df, df$Species)

df_label <- data.frame(
  Species = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"),
  x = c(1, 0, 0),
  reg.y = c(.05, 1, 1),
  hjust = c(1, 0, 0),
  cor.y = c(0, .95, .95)
)
df_label_split <- split(df_label, df_label$Species)

ggscatter(df, x = "Sepal.Length", y = "Sepal.Width", facet.by = "Species", add = "reg.line") +
  purrr::map2(
    df_split, df_label_split,
    function(x, y) {
      list(
        stat_regline_equation(
          data = x, 
          label.x.npc = y$x, label.y.npc = y$reg.y, hjust = y$hjust),
        stat_cor(
          data = x, aes(label = paste(..rr.label.., ..p.label.., sep = "~`,`~")),
          label.y.npc = y$cor.y, hjust = y$hjust, label.x.npc = y$x
        )
      )
    }
  )
```

[image]